# I need my dropdown to show and or hide columns respectively

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, dropdown

my dropdown is numbered to the table list, 1-16. depending on the dropdown number you pick i need that many tables to show. I just started learning Javascript 2 weeks ago so excuse my sloppy coding. I'm also probably going a long roundabout arse way about this, and I am not ready to move on to J-query just yet. the code works but for some reason the 2nd option doesn't show. and the headers on the table shift.

HTML code

```js
function person() {
  var t = document.getElementById("trunk");
  var o = t.options[t.selectedIndex].value;
  var a = document.getElementById("trunk1");
  var x = document.getElementById("trunk2");
  var q = document.getElementById("trunk3");
  var w = document.getElementById("trunk4");
  var e = document.getElementById("trunk5");
  var r = document.getElementById("trunk6");
  var t = document.getElementById("trunk7");
  var y = document.getElementById("trunk8");
  var u = document.getElementById("trunk9");
  var i = document.getElementById("trunk10");
  var z = document.getElementById("trunk11");
  var x = document.getElementById("trunk12");
  var c = document.getElementById("trunk13");
  var v = document.getElementById("trunk14");
  var b = document.getElementById("trunk15");
  var n = document.getElementById("trunk16");

  if (o === "1") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "none";
    q.style.display = "none";
    w.style.display = "none";
    e.style.display = "none";
    r.style.display = "none";
    t.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "none";
    u.style.display = "none";
    i.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "none";
    x.style.display = "none";
    c.style.display = "none";
    v.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "none";
    n.style.display = "none";
  } else  if (o === "2") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    q.style.display = "none";
    w.style.display = "none";
    e.style.display = "none";
    r.style.display = "none";
    t.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "none";
    u.style.display = "none";
    i.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "none";
    x.style.display = "none";
    c.style.display = "none";
    v.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "none";
    n.style.display = "none";
  } else  if (o === "3") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    q.style.display = "block";
    w.style.display = "none";
    e.style.display = "none";
    r.style.display = "none";
    t.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "none";
    u.style.display = "none";
    i.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "none";
    x.style.display = "none";
    c.style.display = "none";
    v.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "none";
    n.style.display = "none";
  } else  if (o === "4") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    q.style.display = "block";
    w.style.display = "block";
    e.style.display = "none";
    r.style.display = "none";
    t.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "none";
    u.style.display = "none";
    i.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "none";
    x.style.display = "none";
    c.style.display = "none";
    v.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "none";
    n.style.display = "none";
  } else  if (o === "5") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    q.style.display = "block";
    w.style.display = "block";
    e.style.display = "block";
    r.style.display = "none";
    t.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "none";
    u.style.display = "none";
    i.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "none";
    x.style.display = "none";
    c.style.display = "none";
    v.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "none";
    n.style.display = "none";
  } else  if (o === "6") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    q.style.display = "block";
    w.style.display = "block";
    e.style.display = "block";
    r.style.display = "block";
    t.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "none";
    u.style.display = "none";
    i.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "none";
    x.style.display = "none";
    c.style.display = "none";
    v.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "none";
    n.style.display = "none";
  } else  if (o === "7") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    q.style.display = "block";
    w.style.display = "block";
    e.style.display = "block";
    r.style.display = "block";
    t.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "none";
    u.style.display = "none";
    i.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "none";
    x.style.display = "none";
    c.style.display = "none";
    v.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "none";
    n.style.display = "none";
  } else  if (o === "8") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    q.style.display = "block";
    w.style.display = "block";
    e.style.display = "block";
    r.style.display = "block";
    t.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "block";
    u.style.display = "none";
    i.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "none";
    x.style.display = "none";
    c.style.display = "none";
    v.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "none";
    n.style.display = "none";
  } else  if (o === "9") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    q.style.display = "block";
    w.style.display = "block";
    e.style.display = "block";
    r.style.display = "block";
    t.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "block";
    u.style.display = "block";
    i.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "none";
    x.style.display = "none";
    c.style.display = "none";
    v.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "none";
    n.style.display = "none";
  } else if (o === "10") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    q.style.display = "block";
    w.style.display = "block";
    e.style.display = "block";
    r.style.display = "block";
    t.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "block";
    u.style.display = "block";
    i.style.display = "block";
    z.style.display = "none";
    x.style.display = "none";
    c.style.display = "none";
    v.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "none";
    n.style.display = "none";
  } else if (o === "11") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    q.style.display = "block";
    w.style.display = "block";
    e.style.display = "block";
    r.style.display = "block";
    t.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "block";
    u.style.display = "block";
    i.style.display = "block";
    z.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "none";
    c.style.display = "none";
    v.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "none";
    n.style.display = "none";
  } else if (o === "12") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    q.style.display = "block";
    w.style.display = "block";
    e.style.display = "block";
    r.style.display = "block";
    t.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "block";
    u.style.display = "block";
    i.style.display = "block";
    z.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    c.style.display = "none";
    v.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "none";
    n.style.display = "none";
  } else if (o === "13") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    q.style.display = "block";
    w.style.display = "block";
    e.style.display = "block";
    r.style.display = "block";
    t.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "block";
    u.style.display = "block";
    i.style.display = "block";
    z.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    c.style.display = "block";
    v.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "none";
    n.style.display = "none";
  } else if (o === "14") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    q.style.display = "block";
    w.style.display = "block";
    e.style.display = "block";
    r.style.display = "block";
    t.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "block";
    u.style.display = "block";
    i.style.display = "block";
    z.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    c.style.display = "block";
    v.style.display = "block";
    b.style.display = "none";
    n.style.display = "none";
  } else if (o === "15") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    q.style.display = "block";
    w.style.display = "block";
    e.style.display = "block";
    r.style.display = "block";
    t.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "block";
    u.style.display = "block";
    i.style.display = "block";
    z.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    c.style.display = "block";
    v.style.display = "block";
    b.style.display = "block";
    n.style.display = "none";
  } else if (o === "16") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    q.style.display = "block";
    w.style.display = "block";
    e.style.display = "block";
    r.style.display = "block";
    t.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "block";
    u.style.display = "block";
    i.style.display = "block";
    z.style.display = "block";
    x.style.display = "block";
    c.style.display = "block";
    v.style.display = "block";
    b.style.display = "block";
    n.style.display = "block";
  }
  
}
```

```html
System Name: <input type="text" name="Channels" placeholder="T-XXXX (Protocol)"> 
<p></p>

<select>
    <option value="Analog Conventional">Analog Conventional</option>
    <option value="LTR Trunking">LTR Trunking</option>
    <option value="NXDN Conventional">NXDN Conventional</option>
    <option value="NXDN Site Roaming">NXDN Site Roaming</option>
    <option value="NXDN Site Roaming with RAN">NXDN Site Roaming with RAN</option>
    <option value="NXDN Trunking" selected="selected">NXDN Trunking</option>
</select>

<p></p>
Number of Personalities: <p></p>
<select id="trunk" onchange="person()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
</select>

<p></p>

<table>

   <tr>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Personality</th>
   </tr>

   <tr id="trunk1" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="trunk2" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">2</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="trunk3" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">3</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="trunk4" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">4</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="trunk5" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">5</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="trunk6" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">6</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="trunk7" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">7</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="trunk8" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">8</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="trunk9" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">9</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="trunk10" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">10</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="trunk11" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">11</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="trunk12" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">12</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="trunk13" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">13</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="trunk14" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">14</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="trunk15" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">15</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="trunk16" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">16</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like a typo.  You can't re-use variable names within the same scope.  This is a good case for starting to use meaningful variable names instead of just letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed some `id`s to classes with the advantage from the selected number you already implemented just loop over the items with some `className string concatenation` .. hope this helps

```js
function person() {
  var t = document.getElementById("trunk");
  var o = t.options[t.selectedIndex].value;
  
  // hide all, in case someone choses to select a lower number
  // then the preivously selected one
  [...document.querySelectorAll('[class^="trunk"]')].forEach(
    trunc => trunc.style.display = 'none'
  );
  
  for(let i=1; i <= o; i++) {
      document.querySelector(".trunk" + i).style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
System Name: <input type="text" name="Channels" placeholder="T-XXXX (Protocol)"> 
<p></p>

<select>
    <option value="Analog Conventional">Analog Conventional</option>
    <option value="LTR Trunking">LTR Trunking</option>
    <option value="NXDN Conventional">NXDN Conventional</option>
    <option value="NXDN Site Roaming">NXDN Site Roaming</option>
    <option value="NXDN Site Roaming with RAN">NXDN Site Roaming with RAN</option>
    <option value="NXDN Trunking" selected="selected">NXDN Trunking</option>
</select>

<p></p>
Number of Personalities: <p></p>
<select id="trunk" onchange="person()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
</select>

<p></p>

<table>

   <tr>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Personality</th>
   </tr>

   <tr class="trunk1" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="trunk2" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">2</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="trunk3" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">3</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="trunk4" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">4</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="trunk5" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">5</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="trunk6" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">6</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="trunk7" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">7</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="trunk8" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">8</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="trunk9" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">9</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="trunk10" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">10</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="trunk11" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">11</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="trunk12" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">12</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="trunk13" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">13</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="trunk14" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">14</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="trunk15" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">15</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="trunk16" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align:center;">16</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Frequency"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is awesome! I can't believe how short this code is! Thank you! I just separated my header as it's own table, that works for me. Again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You declared `var x` twice, for trunk2 and trunk12. Thus making "trunk2" display style to remain "none".